# iOS - Text chat in GKTurnBasedMatch

Tags: ios, gamekit

I am trying to implement a chat feature in a turn-based match using GameKit. I think I can send the messages by calling `[match endTurnWithNextParticipant:match.currentParticipant matchData:dataWithUpdatedChat completionHandler:...]`

In other words, when I want to send a chat message, I end the current player's turn so that the data gets sent to Game Center, but then the current player is next to act so he can proceed normally.

However, I have no way of updating the match data if it is not the current player's turn. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work but maybe send exchanges to all other players with data nul. Upon receiving the event, the devices add the message to the chat window. Match data is never updated. Chat is only local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it. If there was it would be prone to race conditions between players. You need another service to implement a chat feature. Another option is to implement a limited chat in the game, for example an option to enter a message when ending the turn.

Answer (score 0):

The following method was added to `GKTurnBasedMatch` in iOS 6.0 and will do what you need:

```
- (void)saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:(NSData *)matchData
                   completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler
```

"Update the match data without advancing the game to another player"

Comment: The problem with this is that only the player who is currently moving can send a chat message... so it might not end the turn, but it would probably make for some rather boring conveerations.